# Linux on Dragonboard APQ8074

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, dragonboard

I have a DragonBoard APQ8074 with SnapDragon 800. I am able to successfully build Android and run some OpenCL related apps on this.

I am currently trying to build a linux kernel and load either Ubuntu or Fedora on this board.
It wouldbe really helpful if anyone could point me to suitable posts or guides.

I did look into Freedreno, it is really a good starting point, but i am still unable to understand the part of initrd/ramdisk img file.

Also the bootloader (similar to u-boot i assume), i am not clear which parts of it i need to update, if at all necessary.

Thanks in advance.

regard,
Anup.

Answer (score 0):

This might help http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Android. There's a few sections there that might be handy. I also found this other article that helped me understand intrd and intramfs a bit better if that helps. http://www.linux.com/learn/linux-career-center/114923-the-kernel-newbie-corner-qinitrdq-and-qinitramfsq-some-unfinished-business